# Unresolved references in VS2022

Tags: c#

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dieir.png)
I got latest project as a new developer in my company. Same issue occurs to my peers.
I have tried to update windows sdk, add UWP nuget package.
Nothing helps.

I have added screenshot for reference.

Can someone help me here?

tried google, updating windows sdk, added nuget package uwp.
Nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried running [`nuget restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-by-using-the-nuget-cli) on the solution?

Comment: did your UWP or Windows SDK somehow got uninstalled?

Comment: nuget restore didnt work.

Comment: SDK is present and UWP is installed in Visual studio

Comment: Please show the content of your project file - or ideally a [mcve]. (And saying nuget restore "didn't work" isn't *nearly* as useful as adding complete information with error messages into your post. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints)